# Ionic 4 ion-button not updating ngStyle when Variable changes value

Tags: angular, ionic4

I have a page in an Ionic 4 project set up such that when a button is clicked a variable changes value and the ngStyle is meant to be updated. In my case we have two buttons, "Friends" and "Families", when one is selected I want the background green, and the other one clear. On initial setup, this is the case and the friends button is green and the families button is clear. However when I click the families button, the variable changes value to "families", as I can see on the console.log output, but this change is not reflected in the buttons as expected. What happens is the "Families" button gets turned green, but the "Friends" button stays green. From here any more clicks don't change anything.

```
// .ts file

// setting initial variable
selectedCat = "friends";

// functions to update on button click
showFriends() {
    this.selectedCat = "friends";
    console.log('This is this.selectedCat showFriends', this.selectedCat);
  }

  showFamilies() {
    this.selectedCat = "families";
    console.log('This is this.selectedCat showFamilies', this.selectedCat);
  }
```

```
<ion-buttons slot="end">
        
<ion-button expand="block" fill="outline" [ngStyle]="selectedCat == 'friends' ? {'background-color': '#90EE90'} : {'background-color':'clear'}" [color]="dark" (click)="showFriends()" item-left>
              Friends
</ion-button>

<ion-button expand="block" fill="outline" [ngStyle]="selectedCat == 'families' ? {'background-color': '#90EE90'} : {'background-color':'clear'}"  [color]="dark" (click)="showFamilies()" item-left>
              Families
</ion-button>
          
</ion-buttons>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that 'clear' is not a valid color for css. Can you try changing it to a valid html color name shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colornames.asp ?

You could also use 'unset' to 'remove' the background color:

```
<ion-button expand="block" fill="outline" [ngStyle]="selectedCat == 'friends' ? {'background-color': '#90EE90'} : {'background-color':'unset'}" [color]="dark" (click)="showFriends()" item-left>
              Friends
</ion-button>
```